# What is a template in handlebars.js?

Tags: handlebars.js

The handlebars.js documentation introduces a template with this example:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile('{{foo}}');
template({});
```

If one examines the template variable in the console, it contains:

```
function (context, options) {
  if (!compiled) {
    compiled = compile();
 }
 return compiled.call(this, context, options);
}
```

How is this a template?  I understand templates to be some html with variables in it, not a function.

Furthermore, with regards to the call:

```
template({});
```

What is this empty function call all about?  Is this something common and obvious to javascript programmers, eg. am I missing some fundamental knowledge that makes me unable to recognize it?  Or is this some handlebars.js oddity that is simply not well explained in their documentation?

Answer (score 1):

The template is `'{{foo}}'`. When it is compiled, you get a function that takes context; context supplies variable bindings for the template. Thus, `template({ foo: 17 })` should produce `"17"` given the template above. `template({})` will render `{{foo}}` with the representation of `undefined`, producing an empty string.

Comment: Do you feel that the API docs could be better for this example?  http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html

Answer (score 1):

Implementation-wise in Handlebars, a template is a function. You call the function with the template data and get back the populated template.

The template data is an object in which keys correspond to the names inside the {{ }} in the template. The values of those keys get injected into the template where the key name is.

So, in your example, `template({})` produces `""`, but `template({"foo":"blah"})` produces `"blah"`.

A slightly more complete example:

```
var template = Handlebars.compile('{{greeting}}, my name is {{name}}');

template({"greeting":"Hello","name":"Alice"})

// "Hello, my name is Alice"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you feel that your more complete example would serve the API docs better?  See top of http://handlebarsjs.com/reference.html.  I wonder what the reason is for the example code to be so sparse.

Comment: Yeah, I think so. I wouldn't find that doc very helpful if I didn't know Handlebars.